# Docker + windows Container + NodeJs + Angualar

Tags: docker

Error on Docker File Copy Package file

Step 10/13 : COPY src/WebSpa/package.json app/src/WebSpa/package.json
1>COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src\WebSpa\package.json: file does not exist

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803 as installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.10.0/node-v18.10.0-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v18.10.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs
#RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.4.0/node-v12.4.0-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v12.4.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1803

WORKDIR C:/nodejs
COPY --from=installer C:/nodejs/ .
RUN SETX PATH C:\nodejs
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
#
WORKDIR /app
### install and cache app dependencies
COPY C:\src\WebSpa\package.json C:\app\src\WebSpa\package.json
#
#WORKDIR /app/src/WebSpa
#RUN npm install
#RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
#
# add app
COPY . /app

# start app
CMD cd /app/WebSpa && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Able to deploy NodeJS on Windows Base image build on docker container

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.